# Different SKTexture causes insane lag

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I tried making two identical characters (two classes that extend from SKSpriteNode) for the game, the only difference is the SKTexture they're using. I'll refer to them as A and B. Whenever I let A shoot a bullet, it doesn't lag but when I let B shoot a bullet, it lags just a little bit. The problem became clear when I spam shoot from A, it stays at a constant 60 FPS but when I spam shoot from B, it lags, down to around 50 FPS.

A's texture is "Lampy.png" and I tried setting B's texture as "Lampy2.png". Those 2 images are exactly the same, the only difference is the file name, but B lags.

```
override init(){
        super.init()
        playerBody.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Lampy2")
}
```

Code above is from B and it lags

```
override init(){
        super.init()
        playerBody.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Lampy")
}
```

Code above is from A and it does not lag

Other parts of the two classes are exactly the same. Did I import the images incorrectly or something? I can't remember how I imported Lampy but for Lampy2 I dragged it directly from Finder to the assets folder.

Edit - Here's the full class code

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Lampy: Player{

    override init(){
        super.init()
        playerBody.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Lampy")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func shoot(){
        let thiccBullet = Thicc()
        thiccBullet.position = position
        thiccBullet.bulletBody.zRotation = playerBody.zRotation
        thiccBullet.owner = self;
        parent?.addChild(thiccBullet)
    }


}
```

At the line with `playerBody.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Lampy")`
if I change Lampy to Lampy2 then it lags.

Comment: Did you use the same class with 2 different images?  Set A to Lampy2. If it doesn’t lag, then you know it is not the image.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it lagged.

Comment: could you post some code?  You should only be getting the lag once.  If you are getting the lag everytime, and your code is on the up and up, then the system would be invalidating the cache and pulling from the disk every time Lampy2 is used.

Comment: Ok I added the code. So is it a problem that will somehow go away eventually? Sorry if I use weird wordings I'm new to the programming world.

Comment: Wait a minute.... i thought your bullets were made from lampy.... something isnt right here because lampy is only made once.  You are going to have to show lampy, lampy2, thicc, and gamescene so I can understand the flow of your code